# how to remove black background in TweenMax script

Tags: pixi.js, gsap

i using TweenMax and pixi.js

```
codepen.io/nimaina/pen/aPERKO
```

how to remove black background?

Answer (score 1):

Well the black background that you see is the default [PIXI.Application](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Application.html) setup.

> Default width: 800
>
> Default height: 600
>
> Default backgroundColor: 0x000000 (black)

Basically there are two options, that I see, to avoid the black background.

### Option 1: use exact dimensions for width and height

I see the dimensions of [greensock.png](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/314556/greensock.png) are 538x173.

```
var app = new PIXI.Application( {
  view: document.querySelector("#canvas"),
  width: 538,
  height: 173
});
```

### Option 2: set `transparent:true` and make the background transparent

```
var app = new PIXI.Application( {
  view: document.querySelector("#canvas"),
  transparent: true
});
```